# Сделать уникальным конкретный элемент массива

Tags: javascript

Есть строка, где разделитель запятая. Перевожу ее в массив, затем делаю его уникальным и перевожу обратно в строку.

```
arr = searchValue.split(',');
arr = arr.filter( onlyUnique );
searchValue = arr.join(',');

function onlyUnique(value, index, self) {
    return self.indexOf(value) === index;
}
```

Вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы уникальным становился конкретный элемент массива?

Comment: Что значит "уникальным становился конкретный элемент массива"? Т.е. чтобы удалялись только его копии, а остальные копии не удалялись?

Comment: @br3t допустим есть строка вида `var str = 'test, 1, 2, 3, 1, test'`. Поставить такое условие, чтобы после выше приведенного кода, осталось только `test, 1, 2, 3, 1`.

Comment: а почему именно test надо убрать, а не 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно запоминать, было ли выведено уже ваше уникальное значение (переменная `gotcha`). Все остальные значения пропускаем:

```js
var subj = 'test, 1, 2, 3, 1, test';

function ufilter(str, val) {
  var gotcha = false;
  var arr = str.split(',').filter(function(v,i) { 
    if(v.trim() == val) {
      if(!gotcha) {
        gotcha = true;
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    
  });
  return arr.join(',');
}

console.log(ufilter(subj, 'test'));
console.log(ufilter(subj, '1'));
```